# Какие опции есть у native-image?

Tags: java, exe, native

Собственно моя цель - создать из моего [java](/questions/tagged/java)-приложения нативный исполняемый файлик, к примеру у нас будет программа `hello world`. Я компилирую её в байт-код с помощью стандартного инструмента `jdk 17 - javac`, после я работаю уже непосредственно с `native-image`. Я не нашёл таких опций в документации, как `output` - опция, указывающая на то, куда будет перемещен выходной `exe` с `dll`-ками, но если эта проблема решается тем, что надо просто запустить командную строку в нужной директории, а к `jar` указать полный путь, то например такой опции, которая изменит имя процесса будущего приложения я не нашёл.

Может быть это уже не касается `native-image`, а exeшник нужно обрабатывать другой программой, но вопрос какой?

Собственно моя проблема заключается в том, что запуская мой `helloworld.exe`, на котором нет иконки, в диспетчере задач отображается процесс `helloworld.exe`. Как мне изменить имя процесса, чтоб в диспетчере задач отображалось заданное мной красивое имя `Hello World!` и как сменить иконку `exe`, чтоб как на рабочем столе была видна иконка, так и в диспетчере задач была иконка рядом с процессом.

Если это можно сделать на стадии компиляции `native-image`'ом, то: во-первых какие нужны опции именно для смены процесса и смены иконки и, во-вторых, желательно мне скинуть статью с документации `native-image`, где есть такие опции, которые как раз таки связаны с изменением свойств будущего `exe`.

Answer (score 3):

Для задания пути и имени exe-файла есть `-H:Path=` и `-H:Name=`, но это именно про имя файла, а не имя процесса в диспетчере.

Для имени процесса и иконки никаких опций скорее всего нет, но можно попробовать вот что: заранее скомпилировать файл ресурсов (допустим helloworld.res) и подсунуть его линкеру через `-H:NativeLinkerOption`. Включить ещё `-H:+TraceNativeToolUsage` для контроля:

```
native-image -H:+TraceNativeToolUsage -H:NativeLinkerOption=helloworld.res ...
```